# $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$ divide 13 only if $5^n-1$ divide 13, with n in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$ divide 13 only if $5^n-1$ divide 13, with n in $\mathbb{N*}$

I proved that $5^n$ is prime with 13 (n in $\mathbb{N}$)

we have: 13 divide $5^n$-1 $\Rightarrow (13 * \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$) divide $(5^n-1) * \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$

I tried to use Gauss lemma 13 divide $(5^n-1) * \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$ and 13 is prime with $5^n - 1$

$\Rightarrow$ 13 divide $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k)$

the problem I dont have 13 is prime with ($5^n - 1$); I only have 13 is prime with $5^n$

Comment: $5^n$ never divides $13$.  Well, unless you are allowing $n=0$.

Comment: @lulu i meant $5^n−1$ divide 13. sorry, not $5^n$ divide 13

Comment: Well, I think you meant $13$ divides $(5^n-1)$, right?

Comment: Yes! exactly
that's what I meant

Comment: @MalekGara-Hellal Hint: The summation is of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Ok, so we want $5^n\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$.  But that's easily solved, and the least such $n$ is $4$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you!
but I didn't really seem to get that hint
I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k) = \frac{(1-q^n)}{1-q}$
I didn't get the relation between them

Comment: @lulu, my problem is how to prove that that summation is dividable by 13 not the $5^n-1$

Comment: @MalekGara-Hellal You're welcome. Note the summation formula gives $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(5^k) = \frac{5^{n} - 1}{4}$. Thus, if $13 \mid \frac{5^{n} - 1}{4}$, what does that say about whether or not $13$ divides $5^{n} - 1$ (i.e., whether or not $5^{n} - 1$ is divisible by $13$)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh I got you now!
but isn't it wrong to multiple by 1/4? its not an Integer.

Comment: Since $\gcd (13,4)=1$, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MalekGara-Hellal All the division by $4$ means, since we know that $\frac{5^n-1}{4}$ is an integer, is that $4$ is a factor of $5^n - 1$. It doesn't affect whether or not $13$ divides $\frac{5^n - 1}{4}$ (and also $5^n - 1$) because, as Basanta Raj Pahari just commented, we have that $\gcd(4, 13) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I really appreciate the help <3

Just another question, let's call that summation Un. $Un = \frac{(5^n-1)}{4}$, is this correct?
I want to make sure from that so I can use Gauss Lemma: We have 13|($5^n-1$) 
then we have 13|4*($5^n-1$) --> 13|(4*Un).
Using Gauss Lemme 13|(4*Un), 13 and 4 are prime between each other. -->then we have 13|Un